# How to duplicate selected log messages to sysout?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

In places in my code where I want to output a console message /and/ have it logged I'm currently calling both System.out.println /and/ and log.info.

This is, of course, not desirable and I'd like to fix it.  I've been looking at the marker interface in slf4j/logback and am wondering if this is suitable for this task, ie take all log messages which are marked and also send a copy of them to sysout?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the way I've approached this kind of thing is using the wonderful marker mechanism:

To log:

```
private static final Marker notification = MarkerFactory.getMarker("NOTIFICATION");
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
...
log.info(notification, "Important message to go everywhere");
```

And in logback.xml, something like:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
            <marker>NOTIFICATION</marker>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The use case I'm showing here showing all errors as well as anything marked as a "notification" on the console, but you can adapt the filters to show or hide whatever it is you're looking for.